# How can I fix the list index out of range problem?

Tags: python, datetime

So I wanna fill NaN value of the pay date with the date one month after the join date.

| Join date | Payday1 |
| --- | --- |
| Okt'10 | NaN |
| Des'10 | NaN |

My expectation output is:

| Join date | Payday1 |
| --- | --- |
| Okt'10 | Nov'10 |
| Des'10 | Jan'11 |

I try this code:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","Mei","Jun","Jul","Agt","Sep","Okt","Nov","Des"]
dateIn="Okt'10" 

def fill_date():  
  dateIn=dateIn.split("'")
  month, year= dateIn[0], int(dateIn[1])

  if month == months[len(months)-1]: 
    year+=1 
    month=months[0] 
  else:
    for m in months:
        if m == month:
          month=months[months.index(month)+1] 
  dateOut=f"{month} {year}" 

df['Payday1'] = df['Payday1'].apply(fill_date)
```

This code is error in this code month=months[months.index(month)+1], it said `list index out of range`. So how to fix this code ?

Comment: You can try generating a Series based on your existing Join dates for rows that have a NaN on the Payday. You can then pass this to the fillna() function like so: `df['Payday1'].fillna(payday_series, inplace=True)`.

Comment: what is payday_series refer to? it's not define

Comment: It's a placeholder variable for the series you would create containing the values you want to use to fill your column with. You would need to define it.

Comment: probably you could simply add second `Jan` at the end of list to resolve this problem.

Comment: or you should use `break` inside `for`-loop to exit this loop when it find first matching element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see two methods:

**First:** add second `Jan` at the end of list `months` and this may work.

**Second:** use `break` inside `for`-loop to exit it when you find first matching element.

All problem is because inside `if m == month` you assign new value to `month` and in next loops the same line `if m == month` compares with different value in `month` and it may compare with `Des` and tor to get elemenet after `Des`. But if you use `break` then it will exit afer finding first matching value (and it will not check `if m == month` for new value).

---

Full working code with other changes - ie. you fogot `return dateOut` in your code.

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","Mei","Jun","Jul","Agt","Sep","Okt","Nov","Des"]

dateIn = "Okt'10" 

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Join date': ["Okt'10", "Des'10"],
    'Payday1': ["NaN", "NaN"],
})
                  
def fill_date(dateIn):
  print(dateIn)
  
  dateIn = dateIn.split("'")
  month, year = dateIn[0], int(dateIn[1])

  if month == months[-1]: 
     year += 1 
     month = months[0] 
  else:
     for m in months:
        if m == month:
           month = months[months.index(month)+1]
           break  # <--- HERE
          
  dateOut = f"{month}'{year}"
  
  return dateOut
  

df['Payday1'] = df['Join date'].apply(fill_date)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
  Join date Payday1
0    Okt'10  Nov'10
1    Des'10  Jan'11
```

---

Probably problem could resolve also `for m in months[:-1]:` to skip `Des` from list.

Comment: but the result of Payday1 is None

Comment: I get correct text - you forgot `return dateOut` in your code

Comment: What is the for loop doing in this code? Looks a bit unnecessary to me. I would remove it rather than using a break statement.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin it compares month form dataframe with all values on list to get later next value from this list - I tried to keep original version to show where is the problem in current version.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin without this loop this code is useless - but it could be done in different way - ie using `index()` or creating dictionary - but I tried to keep original method.

Comment: @furas You can get the next value without looping. Not sure it's a good idea to break an unnecessary loop when it can be removed all together.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin as I said I try to keep original version - if I remove loop then It will not work (it gives wrong results) and I would have to use something different - and I don't want to use something different.

Comment: @furas The resulting code is idiotic, I don't understand the value of this answer.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin it explains what wrong with original code. It shows where beginner made mistake. Other anwsers show other methods to get result - and I want only to show why original code didn't work.

Comment: @furas the mistake IS the unnecessary for loop

Comment: @JacquesGaudin did you run without loop? I gives wrong results. In first row it gives `Okt'10` instead `Nov'10`

Comment: @furas the two other answers give correct results without looping.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin read my previous comments - I don't want to show result with other methods (other people already did it) I want only to show where is mistake in original code. And it seems OP likes this explanation (instead other methods). I can understand why original code makes mistakes.

Comment: @furas do you agree that the code in this answer is flawed and wouldn't pass a code review?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin read my previous comments - I created it to explain what is wrong with original code - to learn how to recognize and understand mistake in original code. I didn't create it to show the best code which can pass code review - but to explain why original code doesn't work as expected. And this can be also very useful for beginner - to understand where he made mistake. Sometimes it may need to use `for`-loop and it can learn how to recognize mistaka in this code.

Comment: @furas glad you agree

Comment: @JacquesGaudin in all my comments I was saying that my answer is for explaining mistake, not to show different methods. I never said that this code is the best or it can't be replace with something better - but my answer wasn't for showing better version.

Comment: @furas that's why I don't like this answer, nothing personal of course

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def fill_date(dt):
    mapper = {m: i+1 for i, m in enumerate(months)}
    month, year = dt.split("'")
    
    if mapper[month]==12:
        return f"Jan'{int(year)+1}"
    else:
        return f"{months[mapper[month]]}'{year}"
    
df["Payday1"] = df["Join date"].apply(fill_date)
```

###### Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Join date": ["Okt'10", "Des'10"]})
```

Comment: it gets error, AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: What language dates are these? Please provide a constructor for your dataframe using `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: it's still string type

Comment: Then I have no idea how you get that error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to constrain the index between `0` and `len(months)`, you can use the modulo operator `%`.

```
month=months[(months.index(month) + 1) % len(months)]
```

So you would get the following:

```
def fill_date(dateIn):
    dateIn = dateIn.split("'")
    month, year =  dateIn[0], int(dateIn[1])

    year += 1 if month == months[-1] else 0

    month = months[(months.index(month) + 1) % len(months)]
          
    dateOut = f"{month}'{year}"
  
    return dateOut
```

Comment: unfortunately when I tried by this code, it's only success for the last month which change the year

Comment: I made the answer clearer by showing the full function. Hope it helps.